# MKStoreKit doesn't works on iPod 2

Tags: iphone, ipod, mkstorekit

I'm trying to integrate MKStoreKit into my game, but when [MKStoreManager sharedManager] called, app crashes on ipod 2 with error:

dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _objc_retain
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/2EA46519-12C1-4ED8-B19B-ED4AFA178F81/uni.app/uni
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _objc_retain
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/2EA46519-12C1-4ED8-B19B-ED4AFA178F81/uni.app/uni
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib

//latest MKStOreKit, Xcode 4.2.1, on other devices no error occured

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds like an ARC issue to me.

What iOS version is running on the iPod? ARC will work on iOS 4 and above.

Try adding `-fobjc-arc` to the "Other Linker Flags" build setting for your project.

Comment: Setting the option in linker helped and the application on ipod 2 now loads, BUT there occurred a new problem – no response comes (function  (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response is not called). What can be the problem?  In ipod 2 ios 4.2.1, internet works.

I checked on ipod 4 ios 4.3.3 – response comes.